# How to display images in a while loop without crashing it with openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, video, capture, imshow

I am playing a video, in which I am trying to detect something, whenever I detect my region of interest, i want to display it for several seconds:

```
import cv2
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
while True:
    ret,frame = capture.read(0)
    region_of_interest = detect(frame)
    if region_of_interest != 0:
        cv2.imshow('Image',region_of_interest)
        cv2.waitKey(2000)
        cv2.destroyWindow('Image')
    cv2.imshow('Normal Video',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem is that when it finds something, it pops with a lot of windows and then it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your are creating and destroing windows for each loop, try this

```
import cv2
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
while True:
   ret,frame = capture.read(0)
   region_of_interest = detect(frame)

    if region_of_interest != 0:
        # if you want to show somenthing better put a text
        cv2.putText(frame, data, (cord1, cord2), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)


    cv2.imshow('Normal Video',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```